# Out of memory error during evaluation but training works fine

Tags: pytorch

I have recently upgraded PyTorch from 0.2 to 0.3. Surprisingly my old programs are throwing an out of memory error during evaluation (in eval() mode) but training works just fine. I am using the same batch size for training and evaluation. I am totally clueless what is happening? Did anyone face similar issue? Is there any possible solution?

---

I tried using `volatile=True` param on the variables and it didn't help. Please note, I am not doing anything special to use cuDNN. I am using the default setting.

```
def validate(self, dev_corpus):
    # Turn on evaluation mode which disables dropout.
    self.model.eval()

    dev_batches = helper.batchify(dev_corpus.data, self.config.batch_size)
    print('number of dev batches = ', len(dev_batches))

    dev_loss = 0
    num_batches = len(dev_batches)
    for batch_no in range(1, num_batches + 1):
        session_queries, session_query_length, rel_docs, rel_docs_length, doc_labels = helper.session_to_tensor(
            dev_batches[batch_no - 1], self.dictionary)
        if self.config.cuda:
            session_queries = session_queries.cuda()
            session_query_length = session_query_length.cuda()
            rel_docs = rel_docs.cuda()
            rel_docs_length = rel_docs_length.cuda()
            doc_labels = doc_labels.cuda()

        loss = self.model(session_queries, session_query_length, rel_docs, rel_docs_length, doc_labels)
        if loss.size(0) > 1:
            loss = loss.mean()
        dev_loss += loss.data[0]

    return dev_loss / num_batches
```

I am using the above function for evaluation. Here, session_queries, session_query_length, .... rest variables are created by enabling `volatile=True`.

Please help!!

Answer (score 2):

I think it fails during validation because the `volatile` flag is now deprecated and has no effect. Starting from 0.4.0, to avoid the gradient being computed for all variables during validation, you should use a context manager. Code example:

```
with torch.no_grad():
    # Your validation code
```

With that, the operation history and gradients are not stored. Thus this will save memory.

Refer to [0.4.0 migration guide](https://pytorch.org/2018/04/22/0_4_0-migration-guide.html) for more details.

Furthermore, you could delete references to those variables after you finished the evaluation like this:

```
someVar = Variable(someVar)
del someVar
```